# for loop to get distinguished name does not return anything

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

The following code to harvest distinguished name works on all my computers but a few.

```
FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=3*" %%I in ('reg query "hklm\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine" /v Distinguished-Name') DO @ECHO "%%I %%J"
```

I am looking into one XP machine that is exhibiting this, and tried alternatives like the one below to no avail:

```
FOR /F "tokens=3*" %%I in ('reg query "hklm\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine" /v Distinguished-Name |findstr "CN="') DO ECHO "%%I %%J"
```

Interestingly, I get the results just fine if I do not include for /f like this:

```
reg query "hklm\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine" /v Distinguished-Name |findstr "CN="
    Distinguished-Name  REG_SZ  CN=xyz123,OU=Test-5,DC=test,DC=com
```

or

```
reg query "hklm\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine" /v Distinguished-Name

! REG.EXE VERSION 3.0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine
        Distinguished-Name  REG_SZ  CN=xyz123,OU=Test-5,DC=test,DC=com
```

Any ideas what may be going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh! I took that part out of script and forgot to remove '%' so that it should have been %I instead of %%I, which is why nothing was returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%I in ('reg query "hklm\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine" /v Distinguished-Name^|find "REG_SZ"') DO ECHO "%%J"
```

This works with all Windows versions.

Comment: Although I initially thought that the query was not returning what I wanted for a couple of machines, there was really nothing wrong with the query itself. The issue was that I took the line out of script to test it in the command line and of course it did not run as is because of the extra %